# osx login is intermittently locked

Tags: macos, login

I am currently using a global hotkey combo to lock Snow Leopard whenever away from the desk. Every month or so, on returning I am unable to login, even though the password is correct. The only way to login again, is to restart, after which the same password works fine. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this behaviour, or has a fix?

Comment: On a related note - are you sure you're entering the password in correct language? I use Lithuanian/English keyboard layouts and Lithuanian one has numbers replaced with own letters. Since my password uses numbers - I can't enter them while Lithuanian layout is chosen. So make sure you're using ONLY English layout.

Comment: can you log in to the machine using `ssh`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a bug on the machine's OS, when is the last time you reinstalled OSX on that bay... I would just do do simple reinstall, keep the data and flush the settings and start from there... I found that osx (in the latest versions) is alot more dirty then it used to be... Can anyone say iTunes ; )

Later,